# `rm` and Mac OS X's Versions feature

Tags: macos, versions

I assume that deleting a file via Finder also deletes any previous versions in `/.DocumentRevisions-V100` that are attached to that file.

But what's happening if a file is deleted in Terminal with the `rm` command? Are previous versions left behind or do they actually get deleted, too?

Answer (score 6):

`rm` just deletes the file(s) specified on the command line. So if you need to delete additonal files from `/.DocumentRevisions-V100` you need to delete them explicitely as well.